# Grothendieck group of the heart of a bounded $t$-structure.

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

My ultimate goal is to prove that given a heart $\mathcal{C}$ of a bounded $t$-structure $(\mathcal{T}^{\leq 0}, \mathcal{T}^{\geq 0})$ in a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$, that the Grothendieck groups are isomorphic $K\mathcal{T}\cong K\mathcal{C}$, where the former is defined in the sense of triangulated categories, and the latter in terms of Abelian categories.

For reference, this is *Proposition A.9.5* of Achar's book on Perverse Sheaves and Representation theory, the exercise being left to the reader.

Now, I know that the zeroth $t$-chomology functor ${}^tH^0$ is a cohomological functor, and that for all pairs of arrows $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the sequence $0\to X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\to 0$ is exact iff there's a morphism $h$ making
$X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\xrightarrow{h}$ into a distinguished triangle.  Thus, inspired by the notion of Euler characteristic, I hoped that for $X\in \mathcal{T}$, letting $[-]$ denote the isomorphism class of $-$, that the map
$[X]\mapsto \sum_{\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n [{}^tH^n(X)]$ would serve as the inverse to the map induced by the inclusion $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{T}$. However it's here I'm stuck....

Of course, I thought to just consider the case of the bounded derived category $D^b(\mathcal{A})$ of an Abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, and the heart of the natural $t$-structure first, and then let that inspire the approach. (That is, complexes up to quasi-iso and the heart of complexes concentrated  Though even here, I'm stuck for what to do.  While it makes "spiritual" sense to me that for a complex $A$ we should find $\sum_{\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n [H^n(A)]=[A]$ (after including back into $KD^b(\mathcal{A})$) I'm not sure how to prove this.

Achar says the proof of that A.9.5 is similar to the very simple proof of a theorem he offers shortly before, but I just don't see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already argued why the canonical map $K\mathcal{C} \to K\mathcal{T}$ is injective, it remains to argue surjectivity. In other words, given an object $X$ of $\mathcal{T}$, we have to argue that $[X] \in K\mathcal{T}$ lies in the image of $K\mathcal{C}$.

First assume that $X \in \mathcal{T}_{=n}$ is concentrated in a single degree $n$. Using the exact sequence
\begin{aligned}
    X \to 0 \to X[1],
\end{aligned}
one sees that $[X] = -[X[1]]$ in $K\mathcal{T}$, showing that $[X]$ is in the image of $K\mathcal{C}$ if and only if $[X[1]]$ is. By induction, this shows the claim when $X \in \mathcal{T}_{=n}$.

Now consider an arbitrary object $X$ of $\mathcal{T}$. Since $\mathcal{T}$ is bounded, it lives in a range $[n,m]$ for some integers $m \geq n$. Fixing $n$, we will prove by induction on $m$ that $[X] \in K\mathcal{T}$ lies in the image of $K\mathcal{C}$. The case $m = n$ was treated before, so assume $m > n$ and assume we've proved the claim for $m - 1$. Now pick a distinguished triangle
\begin{aligned}
X_{\geq m} \to X \to X_{< m},
\end{aligned}
with $X_{\geq m}\in \mathcal{T}_{\geq m}$ and $X_{< m} \in \mathcal{T}_{< m}$. Then the statement holds for $X_{\geq m} \in \mathcal{T}_{=m}$ and $X_{<m} \in \mathcal{T}_{[n,m-1]}$ by the previous step and the induction hypothesis, respectively. Since we have $[X] = [X_{\geq m}] + [X_{<m}]$ in $K\mathcal{T}$, this finishes the proof.